# Exce/VBA:l Copy Last Row to Specific columns?

Tags: vba

Hello how can I find the last Row in Excel and copy this Row Down ? I like not to copy the hole row but rather Column #7 to #15 for example. The name of the sheet is `“Forrest”.`
I just started to use VBA, and this is quite confusing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code below should perform the Task you are looking for. Little hint: In Excel you can record Macros and then check in the VBA space how your Actions are transformed into VBA Code, usually this is a good starting Point to learn VBA.

```
Dim lastRowI As Integer
lastRowI = Sheets("Forrest").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Forrest").Activate
Sheets("Forrest").Range(Cells(lastRowI, 7), Cells(lastRowI, 15)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Forrest").Range(Cells(lastRowI + 1, 7), Cells(lastRowI + 1, 15)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I tried the Macro Recording functionality, this is very helpful ! Thank You !